# Pyspark join datasets -duplicate column

Tags: join, pyspark

i am trying to join 2 datasets having columns with same name in pyspark - and join failes with duplicate column error.

```
id      name   color
123456  Rose   Yellow
456789  Jasmine white
789654  Lily    Purple
```

2nd dataset looks like this

```
id      name   Place
123456  Rose   Canada
456789  Jasmine US
333444  Lily Purple
```

I want to join these where id and name matches..  and get the output with inner join, where id and name matches in both datasets..

```
id      name   color      Place 
123456  Rose   Yellow     Canada
456789  Jasmine white     US
```

I tried to write a pyspark function like this

```
def trial(df1,df2):

join_df = df1.join(df2, ["id","name"], how='inner')
join_df.show()
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: what’s the exact error have you got?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if that is the problem but the join works for me standalone. Possibly you are missing indents in your function definition?

Did you try something like the below (note the indents)?

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("123456","Rose","Yellow"),("123456","Jasmine","white"),("789654","Lily","Purple")])).toDF(*["id","name","color"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([("123456","Rose","Canada"),("123456","Jasmine","US"),("333444","Lily","Purple")])).toDF(*["id","name","Place"])

def trial(df1, df2):
    df3 = df1.join(df2, ["id", "name"], how="inner")
    df3.show()

trial(df1, df2)
```

That should result in:

```
+------+-------+------+------+
|    id|   name| color| Place|
+------+-------+------+------+
|123456|Jasmine| white|    US|
|123456|   Rose|Yellow|Canada|
+------+-------+------+------+
```

If that does not work for you perhaps enhance your question with version information or other details.